# Sorting data by a column without in SELECT list

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, select

```
     SELECT old.REF_ID, old.DATE FROM REFID_HISTORY old 
     INNER JOIN REFID_HISTORY new 
     ON new.REF_ID = old.REF_ID 
UNION
     SELECT new.REF_ID, new.DATE FROM REFID_HISTORY new
     INNER JOIN REFID_HISTORY old
     ON new.REF_ID = old._REF_ID
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

Above script show the genealogy of `REFID`. How can  `REF_ID` be sorted by`DATE` without selecting it?

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  The two subqueries appear to return the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your query as a subquery and then select only those columns which you want to show. Like this:

```
SELECT REF_ID
FROM (
      SELECT old.REF_ID, old.DATE FROM REFID_HISTORY old 
      INNER JOIN REFID_HISTORY new 
      ON new.REF_ID = old.REF_ID 
      UNION
      SELECT new.REF_ID, new.DATE FROM REFID_HISTORY new
      INNER JOIN REFID_HISTORY old
      ON new.REF_ID = old._REF_ID
     ) t
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

I created a sample demo have a look:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5e9e8/3

**EDITED:**
**Q. For Cust_ID = 'ABC123'**

```
SELECT REF_ID
FROM (
      SELECT old.REF_ID, old.CUST_ID,old.DATE FROM REFID_HISTORY old 
      INNER JOIN REFID_HISTORY new 
      ON new.REF_ID = old.REF_ID 
      UNION
      SELECT new.REF_ID, new.CUST_ID, new.DATE FROM REFID_HISTORY new
      INNER JOIN REFID_HISTORY old
      ON new.REF_ID = old._REF_ID
     ) t
WHERE CUST_ID = 'ABC123'
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

Comment: sorry, i am thinking to enhance this script with a WHERE clause in main query,cust_id='ABC123' but i hit `invalid identifier`

Comment: Provide table and it's column then i will try to help

Comment: Name                   Null?    Type         
---------------------- -------- ------------ 
CUST_ID            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32) 
REF_ID              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32) 
DATE                  DATE

Comment: `CUST_ID` and `REF_ID` are both PK, would like to query all `REF_ID` where CUST_ID=`xxx`

Comment: What query you created??

Comment: as per your question by putting `WHERE CUST_ID='xxx' `in front of `ORDER BY`

Comment: because column Cust_id is not in the query how can you use it to filter data so that's why i added it in the sub queries

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the query.  Why not just do this?

```
SELECT h.REF_ID
FROM REFID_HISTORY h
ORDER BY h.DATE DESC;
```

It seems much simpler than your approach.